# Android Push Notification Permissions

Tags: android, push-notification

I am using PushBots for notifications in my application. I am using Android Studio as IDE. I am sure that my g2d permissions are correct. When I try to open my app on Virtual Device using Android Studio it works well, but when I try it on a real device (lollipop 5.1) it "unfortunately stopped" and close. I really don't know what is wrong with that... Thanks in advice.

This is my logcat log:

```
04-14 01:17:43.769  23197-23197/com.madtriangle.orbitals E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.madtriangle.orbitals, PID: 23197
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.madtriangle.orbitals/com.madtriangle.orbitals.AndroidLauncher}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application does not define permission com.madtriangle.orbitals.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2658)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application does not define permission com.madtriangle.orbitals.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
            at com.pushbots.google.gcm.GCMRegistrar.checkManifestFile(GCMRegistrar.java:147)
            at com.pushbots.push.Pushbots.check(Pushbots.java:221)
            at com.pushbots.push.Pushbots.init(Pushbots.java:102)
            at com.madtriangle.orbitals.AndroidLauncher.onCreate(AndroidLauncher.java:70)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2611)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

and this is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.madtriangle.orbitals"
    android:versionCode="6"
    android:versionName="1.14">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <permission android:name="com.madtriangle.orbital.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.madtriangle.orbitals.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive dataf message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/GdxTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.madtriangle.orbitals.AndroidLauncher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.madtriangle.ultrasquares.MESSAGE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.pushbots.push.PBListener"/>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.pushbots.google.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
                <category android:name="com.madtriangle.paddle"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.pushbots.push.DefaultPushHandler"/>

        <service android:name="com.pushbots.push.GCMIntentService"/>
        <service
            android:name="org.openudid.OpenUDID_service"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="org.openudid.GETUDID"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="@string/app_id"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved it,

should be (letter s is missing in package name)